# ActionBar title disappears when I change the style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm trying change my ActionBar style, changing the background and title color. The background is ok, but when I try change the `titleTextStyle` the title that I defined on manifest disappear.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">@color/dark</item>
            <item name="background">@color/dark</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/icons</item>
            <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle|useLogo</item>
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleStyle</item>
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
           <item name="android:textColor">@color/icons</item>
        </style>
```

I have another doubt about the color of default icons. For example, I'm using NavigationDrawer and would like to change the color of your icon

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```